# Unity - SendMessage but for variable instead of function/method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there an equivalent of SendMessage to change variable instead of calling a function?

For example, I have:

```
for(int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++)
{
    elements[i].SendMessage("selectMe", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
}
```

and then:

```
public bool selected;
public void selectMe()
{
    selected = true;
}
```

so selectMe() is just an additional step. Is there a way to switch value of "selected" itself? GetComponent<>() is out of question since variable is located in different scripts, depending on object - all of which do indeed contain variable "selected".

In short, I'm looking for something like:

```
elements[i].SendMessage("selected", true, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
```

(above doesn't return an error but it doesn't work either)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a pretty one-liner, but there is a way if you use C# Reflection:

```
foreach (Component comp in GetComponents<Component>()) {
    // Modify this to filter out candidate variables
    const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | 
                               BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static;

    // Change any 'selected' field that is also a bool
    FieldInfo field = comp.GetType().GetField("selected", flags);
    if (field != null  && field.FieldType == typeof(bool)) {
        field.SetValue(true);
    }

    // Change any 'selected' property that is also a bool
    PropertyInfo property = comp.GetType().GetProperty("selected", flags);
    if (property != null && property.PropertyType == typeof(bool)) {
        property.SetValue(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought of it as a solution but yeah, it's not pretty and is actually more lines. Will accept as answer if nothing gets closer.

Comment: @MrQuestions I edited my answer to include type checks, so you only change "selected" variables that are also `bool` type.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't You just make something like this?

```
private bool selected;

public void Select(bool select)
{
    this.selected = select;
}
```

and then:

```
element.SendMessage("Select", true, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
```

But if you want shorter and in my opinion better solution try using events

Comment: That's literally what I wrote above though. I used it when "selectMe" had bigger number of lines, but I exported much of them into "selected"s "get; set". Now that it's literally one line function I want to get rid of it.

Comment: As a sidenote, I'll probably end up using this since I had "selectMe" and "deselectMe". Thumbs up, but ultimately doesn't address the question.